# Personal Macro not functioning: Selecting range and pasting into body of Outlook email

Tags: excel, vba

While piecing together this code, I was able to get it function properly. Thinking I was done, I submitted it to someone who tried to add it as a personal macro and that was when we realized it didn't work the same. To verify, I added it as a personal macro on my own computer and it still didn't work.

I have blindly tried a handful of code additions such as `ChartObject.Activate` after `ThisWorkbook.Activate` but have not had success.

```
Sub RangeToEmailBody()

        Dim TempFilePath As String
        Dim xOutApp As Object
        Dim xOutMail As Object
        Dim xHTMLBody As String
        Dim xRg As Range
        On Error Resume Next
        Set xRg = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please select the data range:", Type:=8)
        If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        With Application
            .Calculation = xlManual
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            .EnableEvents = False
        End With
        Set xOutApp = CreateObject("outlook.application")
        Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        Call createJpg(ActiveSheet.Name, xRg.Address, "DashboardFile")
        TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
        xHTMLBody = "<span LANG=EN>" _
                & "<p class=style2><span LANG=EN><font FACE=Calibri SIZE=3>" _
                & "<img src='cid:DashboardFile.jpg'>"
        With xOutMail
            .Subject = ""
            .HTMLBody = xHTMLBody
          .Attachments.Add TempFilePath & "DashboardFile.jpg", olByValue
            .To = " "
            .Cc = " "
            .Display
        End With
End Sub

Sub createJpg(SheetName As String, xRgAddrss As String, nameFile As String)

    Dim xRgPic As Range
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Worksheets(SheetName).Activate
    Set xRgPic = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Range(xRgAddrss)
    xRgPic.CopyPicture
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).ChartObjects.Add(xRgPic.Left, xRgPic.Top, xRgPic.Width, xRgPic.Height)
        .Activate
        .Chart.Paste
        .Chart.Export Environ$("temp") & "\" & nameFile & ".jpg", "JPG"
    End With
    Worksheets(SheetName).ChartObjects(Worksheets(SheetName).ChartObjects.Count).Delete

Set xRgPic = Nothing
End Sub
```

I would expect the selected range to show up in the body of the email but as a personal macro, there is no content inside the "picture".

Comment: Well `TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"` is conditional based on what computer you're using - are you sure the other person has this file in their computer in the same location?

Comment: Also, remove `On Error Resume Next` and rerun. Do any errors occur, and if so what is the error message?

Comment: @dwirony : I am not sure what this means but I've also tried to add it as a personal macro on my computer with the same result.

Comment: @BigBen : Upon removing that I get the following error: Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range. Upon clicking debug, it highlights the line: Worksheets(SheetName).Activate

Comment: This means that `ThisWorkbook` doesn't have a sheet with that name. Note that you don't normally need to `Activate` though.

Comment: Wait, so `ThisWorkbook` refers to the personal macro workbook. The range you want to create a jpeg from is in a different one, correct?

Comment: @BigBen I have renamed the sheet to 'Sheet1' so with On Error Resume Next still commented out I end up outlook opening up the image with blank squares/rectangles instead of what I highlighted in my sheet.

Comment: @BigBen If I am understanding you correctly then yes! The entirety of my code is placed in Module1 of my Personal Workbook. The range (or image in this case) would be from any workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a guess at the problem. If you're adding this in a personal macro, `ThisWorkbook` refers to the personal workbook. I'm guessing your source range is in a different workbook entirely.

To simplify, I'd do something like this, using a temporary new workbook:

```
Sub createJpg(rng As Range, nameFile As String)

    Dim tempChartObj As ChartObject
    Dim tempWb As Workbook

    Set tempWb = Workbooks.Add
    Set tempChartObj = tempWb.Sheets(1).ChartObjects.Add(rng.Left, rng.Top, rng.Width, rng.Height)

    rng.CopyPicture
    With tempChartObj
        .Activate
        .Chart.Paste
        .Chart.Export Environ$("temp") & "\" & nameFile & ".jpg", "JPG"
    End With

    tempWb.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

Then call it like this (note that `Call` is unnecessary):

```
createJpg xRg, "DashboardFile"
```

Comment: If I redid the code correctly, this solution still doesn't produce the expected image. It is a singular rectangle which mimics the shape of my selected range but I think this is definitely a step in the right direction so that's awesome. Will tackle this with fresh eyes tomorrow! Thanks again!

Comment: Everything seems to be working smoothly! I apparently don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer but thanks for all of your help.